# Add quotes to values of an array using collect

Tags: ruby, arrays

This is my array `[1, 6, 8, 16, 21]`.  I would like it to be `["1", "6", "8", "16", "21"]`

I have tried:

```
[1, 6, 8, 16, 21].collect {|x| "x" }
=> ["x", "x", "x", "x", "x"]
```

Is using collect the right way to?  How do I format the collect function to get quotes around my values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are not understanding what those quotes mean. What you really want is to take an array of *integers* and convert is to an array of *strings*.

```
a = [1, 6, 8, 16, 21]
a.map(&:to_s)
# => ["1", "6", "8", "16", "21"]
```

Here each element from `a` is *mapped* to the `to_s` method, which returns a string representation of the number.

Comment: This is shorthand, but I like this solution.

Comment: Yes, I was trying [1, 6, 8, 16, 21].each { |n| n.to_s } and getting [1, 6, 8, 16, 21]

Comment: `each` yields each element in the collection, but does no modification on the reciever. `map` and `collect` on the other hand, maps each element of the collection to the result of evaluating the block with the corresponding element as argument.

Comment: @nicooga map does not modify the receiver either. The difference is what they return.

Comment: oops, true. I mean, `map!`.

Answer (score 5):

You want to turn numbers into strings? Try this then:

```
[1, 6, 8, 16, 21].map(&:to_s)
```

or the full form

```
[1, 6, 8, 16, 21].map{|i| i.to_s }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use string interpolation as you are trying in your example. You just need to put your variable into `#{}`in your string in double quotes: `"#{ variable }"`.

```
[1, 6, 8, 16, 21].collect {|x| "#{x}" } # "x" will just return string "x"
```